# Delegate complicated exception handling to separate class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I've been trying to follow the default rule of using composition over inheritance to share functionality between classes, but have run into a situation where an existing base class' method's very complicated exception handling now needs to be specialized for certain sub-classes (multiple).

So the exception handling in the base class is something like:

```
try {
    doSomething()
} catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    // complicated logic
} catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
    // complicated logic
} catch (RestClientException ex) {
    // complicated logic
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

But now for certain extensions of this base class, we want to first check for a certain type of `HttpClientErrorException` and do special logic instead.  Instead of parenting the classes that need this special logic to a new base class that extends the original base class, should we consider creating a separate exception handler interface and injecting it into the base class?

An implementation of the interface would implement `handleException` which might look something like:

```
public void handleException(Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof HttpClientErrorException ) {
        // complicated logic
    }
    ..etc..
}
```

Is this considered bad practice?  Are there drawbacks I'm not seeing?  If so, what is the preferred way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could consider using *composition* instead of inheritance. For example, the *decorator pattern*. This will allow more flexible implementation of the layered structure, easily insert new layers and perform pre and post-processing of calls between them, including exception handling.